# Как в react правильно сделать ссылку на внешний сайт?

Tags: react-router

Делаю в react внутренние ссылки при помощи роутов:

```
<NavLink to='/lost' className='nav-link'>Lost</NavLink>
```

Как при помощи NavLink правильно сделать ссылку на ВНЕШНИЙ сайт?

Comment: тэг <a> для вас умер?

Comment: он уже в прошлом

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос снимается, нашел ответ:

```
<Route path='/facebook' component={() => {
                    window.location.href = 'https://www.facebook.com/'
                }}/>
```

и

```
<NavLink to='/facebook' target='_blank' className='nav-link d-inline'><FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon.faFacebook} size='2x' fixedWidth/></NavLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<NavLink>` и `<Link>` используются для перемещения по роутам твоего SPA.
Для ссылок на внешние ресурсы юзай старый добрый тег .

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/" className="nav-link d-inline" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon.faFacebook} size='2x' fixedWidth/>
</a>
```